# I'm trying print data from my response but there is an error

Tags: json, swift

I can print only 1 data, not any more. This is my error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

This is my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "Guides": [
            {
                "_id": "5cbc780edfdb6307006aec37",
                "Text": "He is one of Soroush Friend",
                "Tavernier": 2
            },
            {
                "_id": "5cbc781bdfdb6307006aec38",
                "Text": "He is one of Soroush Friend",
                "Tavernier": 2
            }
        ]
     }
]
```

And this is my struct that works well:

```
struct GuideStruct: Codable {
    let guides: [Guide]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case guides = "Guides"
    }
}

struct Guide: Codable {
    let id, text: String
    let tavernier: Int
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id"
        case text = "Text"
        case tavernier = "Tavernier"
    }
}
```

And this is my array and my class:

```
internal static var guides = [guidesarr]()

class guidesarr {
    var _id : String
    var Text : String
    var Tavernier : Int
    init(_id : String,Text : String,Tavernier : Int) {
        self._id = _id
        self.Text = Text
        self.Tavernier = Tavernier
    }
}
```

And my codes in viewcontroller:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
    typealias guide1 = [GuideStruct]
    var i1 = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let  headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json","OAtcp":"0!QSJ5SDG8Q39PPM$DXP5HD1E10"]
        Alamofire.request("http://192.168.1.100:3535/DarkDiamonds/Api/GetActiveGames",method :.post,headers: headers).responseJSON { (newresponse) in
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let responseguide = try decoder.decode(guide1.self, from: newresponse.data!)
                for each1 in responseguide {
                    let newstruct = guidesarr(_id:each1.guides[self.i1].id , Text: each1.guides[self.i1].text,                     Tavernier: each1.guides[self.i1].tavernier)
                    self.i1 = self.i1 + 1
                    AppDelegate.guides.append(newstruct)
                }
                print(AppDelegate.guides[0])
                print(AppDelegate.guides[1])
                print(AppDelegate.Games.count)
                print(AppDelegate.guides[0].Text)
                print(AppDelegate.guides[1].Text)
            }catch {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can print:

```
print(AppDelegate.guides[0])
```

And print this:

```
print(AppDelegate.guides[0].Text)
```

But when I want to print this:

```
print(AppDelegate.guides[1])
print(AppDelegate.guides[1].Text)
```

There is error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: There's only 1 object in your `guides` array which makes sense since there is only one dictionary in the top level JSON array.

Comment: i dont understand.what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

1. The `guidesarr` class is unnecessary. Just use your `Guide` struct.
2. Use proper naming conventions. Class, struct, and enum names should start with uppercase letters. Property, function, and case names should start with lowercase letters.
3. Don't force-unwrap `data`. Safely check it and do proper error checking.
4. Your main issue is that the two chunks of data you seem to actually want are the two `Guide` instances inside the one (not two) `GuideStruct` instances.

I would redo your code something like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json","OAtcp":"0!QSJ5SDG8Q39PPM$DXP5HD1E10"]
        Alamofire.request("http://192.168.1.100:3535/DarkDiamonds/Api/GetActiveGames", method: .post, headers: headers).responseJSON { (newresponse) in
            if let data = newresponse.data {
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let guides = try decoder.decode([GuideStruct].self, from: data)
                    for guideStruct in guides {
                        AppDelegate.guides.append(contentsOf: guideStruct.guides)
                    }
                    print(AppDelegate.guides[0])
                    print(AppDelegate.guides[1])
                    print(AppDelegate.Games.count)
                    print(AppDelegate.guides[0].Text)
                    print(AppDelegate.guides[1].Text)
                }catch {
                    // Bad JSON
                }
            } else {
                // No data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And change:

```
internal static var guides = [guidesarr]()
```

to:

```
internal static var guides = [Guide]()
```

And delete the `guidearr` class.